# String initialization confusion in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I was trying to call the main function inside the main function i have tried the following code and got successfully compiled code.

```
class test
{
  static int i = 0;

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String asda[] = {"!2312"};

    if (++i == 1)
      main(asda);
  }
}
```

But the error occurs in case of the following code:

```
class test
{
  static int i = 0;

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    if (++i == 1)
      main({"!2312"});
  }
}
```

this made me so confused. the confusion is that  String array initialization is done like `String A[]={"asdf","Asdf");` then why is it giving an error in the second case?
I'm using java 8u40.

Comment: There is nothing to be solved. In first case, compiler knows exactly array type--it stands on the left. In second he doesn't.

Comment: In addition to the (correct) answers: The initialization with `{...}` is only allowed while declaring a variable.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for what you're looking for is:

```
main(new String[]{"!2312"});
```

In your first example, Java is smart enough to know that you're creating a String array, since it's in the String[] declaration part. But since you don't have that in your second example, Java isn't smart enough to know that's a String array, or an array of Objects. So you need to specifically tell Java that it's a String array by including the String[] part.

Edit: I will also note that you could use **varargs** instead of an array as the argument to your main() method:

```
public static void main(String... args){
```

And then you can call your main() method with a String literal instead of an array, just like this:

```
main("!2312");
```

Your whole program might look something like this:

```
public class Main{
    static int i = 0;
    public static void main(String... args){
        if (++i == 1){
            main("!2312");
        }
    }
}
```

That's slightly outside your question, but it might be useful for you to know.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with literals like `{"!2312"}` is that they do not have type information. E.g., Java has no way of knowing if you mean a `String[]` with one value or an `Object[]` with one value. You need to explicitly specify it, either by initializing a variable:

```
String asda[]={"!2312"};
if(++i==1)
    main(asda);
```

or by calling the `new` operator:

```
if(++i==1)
    main(new String[]{"!2312"});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the previous code when you passed asda to main through

```
main(asda);
```

asda was an array but {"!2312"} is not an array and the main method accepts string arrays as specified in the declaration

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

where args is an array. So you should pass an array to main.
Create an array then place that string literal in it and then pass it to main.